How Can I Find a List of Alcoholic Beverages Sold in Each State in the USA?
For a work project, I need some information about alcoholic beverages sold in each state of the USA. Specifically, I'm looking for data on product names and sizes (e.g., "Captain Morgan Original Spiced Rum, 750ml") for each state individually. The data we currently have isn't very useful. Does anyone know or have an idea for where I might find or scrape this information?
Thank you all so much in advance.

I can relatively confidently say that this data does not exist on the Internet.  There are bits and pieces of it, for instance, you can view the North Carolina Alcoholic Beverage Control Commission's warehouse stocks of spirituous liquors, but that won't tell you anything about the beer or wine, or other alcohol products that are sold via producers and independent retailers throughout the state.
You can't even find that much information in many other states, like South Carolina, which doesn't centrally manage spirituous liquor sales like North Carolina, and all alcohol sales are via commercial distributors and retailers.

I see, thanks for the answer.
